# MaxFileSize in timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy not work?

Tags: java, logging, logback, apache-nifi

In NiFi-0.6.1 ,i have try to reduce size of nifi-app.log to be stored in local directory.

In that conf\logback.xml i have configured "MaxFileSize" to be 1MB.I think this only stores nifi-app.log should be under 1 MB Size only.But it doesn't do like that.It always store every logs.

```
<appender name="APP_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>logs/nifi-app.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!--
              For daily rollover, use 'app_%d.log'.
              For hourly rollover, use 'app_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log'.
              To GZIP rolled files, replace '.log' with '.log.gz'.
              To ZIP rolled files, replace '.log' with '.log.zip'.
            -->
            <fileNamePattern>./logs/nifi-app_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <!-- keep 30 log files worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>1</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{40} %msg%n</pattern>
            <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

Now i need to set 1MB for nifi-app.log.

**How to set size for nifi-app.log?**

Answer (score 0):

It appears this was a bug in the 0.X versions of Nifi, as discussed [here](http://apache-nifi.1125220.n5.nabble.com/MaxFileSize-in-timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy-not-work-td16206.html).

This has been fixed for later versions of Nifi, so using these is probably the most desirable method to resolve the issue.